# PHP Form Handling with Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a page that takes questions from the database and auto generates a survey page. This data is then sent to the same form using POST. The code then breaks down the question into Checkbox/Radio button type, and stores the answer appropriately.

This works perfectly for my radio button type question, **but for the checkbox types, only the last selected option is present in the $_POST data.**

This is the generated HTML of a sample checkbox question -

```
1 . Question One 
  <br/>
<fieldset>

        <label for="check[0]">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check[0]" name="check[0]" value="Opt One" required="required" minlength="2">Opt One 
  </label>

   <br />
      <label for="check[1]"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check[1]" name="check[0]" value="Opt Two">Opt Two 
  </label>

   <br />
      <label for="check[2]"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check[2]" name="check[0]" value="Opt Three">Opt Three 
  </label>

   <br />
      <label for="check[3]"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check[3]" name="check[0]" value="Opt Four">Opt Four 
  </label>

   <br />
    <label for="0" class="error" style="display:none"> Please select at least one option. </label>
  <br/>
</fieldset>
```

For example if this was the only question and I select "Opt One" and "Opt Two", then print_r($_POST) shows the following -

```
Array ( [check] => Array ( [0] => Opt Two )
```

Which basically means that Question ID 0's selected option is Opt Two (Opt One has been missed out here).

I can show more code if needed, but as of now I feel this has something to do with my HTML Syntax.

Comment: give different name for check boxs and try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Opt One" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Opt Two" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Opt Three" checked>

<?php print_r( $_POST["check"] ); ?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Opt One, [1] => Opt Two, [2] => Opt Three )
```

Comment: Will this also work if I use name="check0[]" and name="check1[]" ?

Update : Ok so it works, but is the way I named it a bad programming practice or is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `name=check[]` and then see what you get in `$_POST`

Comment: This would work if I had one question only right? Won't it clash if I had a second question?

Comment: It will make an array with the options that are selected